# How paging toolbar to display all record and remove attribute?

Tags: extjs

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', {
    pageSize : pageSize,
    pageable : false,
    proxy: {
        autoload : true,
        type: 'ajax',
        url : url,
        extraParams : {
            deptno : ''
            ,hiredate : ''
            ,job : ''
          ,ename : ''
          ,paging : paging
        },
        reader: {
            type : 'json',
            root : 'list',
            totalProperty : 'totalCount'
        }
    }
});


store.remove(store.pageSize);
store.remove(store.getConfig().pageSize);
```

I want to remove pageSize attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
store.setPageSize(0);
```

you must use store functions in these cases, probably you can try to set it manually following the path with some console logs.

Comment: i think your answer is not working ..? however your source is result paging attritube remove not ..

Comment: you can't remove an attribute, you can only mask his utility setting it to a not useful value

Answer (score 0):

Set the page size to 0 on defining the class:

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', {
    // ...
    pageSize: 0,
    // ...
});
```